# True versus Correct in uttered speech

Tags: pali-canon, ethics, scripture

In the below passage from [MN 58](https://suttacentral.net/mn58/en/sujato?layout=plain&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

> In the same way, prince, the Realized One does not utter speech that he knows to be untrue, false, and pointless, and which is disliked by others.

> The Realized One does not utter speech that he knows to be true and correct, but which is harmful and disliked by others.

> The Realized One knows the right time to speak so as to explain what he knows to be true, correct, and beneficial, but which is disliked by others.

> The Realized One does not utter speech that he knows to be untrue, false, and pointless, but which is liked by others.

> The Realized One does not utter speech that he knows to be true and correct, but which is harmful, even if it is liked by others.

> The Realized One knows the right time to speak so as to explain what he knows to be true, correct, and beneficial, and which is liked by others. Why is that? Because the Realized One has compassion for sentient beings.

There seem to be some (three?) couplets (and a triplet?): 'true/untrue', 'correct/false', 'beneficial/pointless/harmful', and 'likeable/dislikeable'.

My reason for posting is to ask the difference between 'true' and 'correct', but if anyone has anything more general to say about these guidelines, that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Correct might mean not to gossip or preach things unnecessarily even if they are true.

Comment: I think "gossip" is the "pointless/beneficial" pair -- not "true/untrue" nor "correct/false".

Comment: @Ukh from my further reading, i think 'correct' may mean something related to '(conversationally) socially/customarily appropriate', but that's as far as I've gotten

Answer (score 4):

Based on the PTS dictionary entries for [taccha](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=taccha&searchhws=yes&matchtype=default) and [bhūta](https://dsal.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/app/pali_query.py?qs=bhuta&searchhws=yes&matchtype=default):

- > *Taccha*: ... true, real, justified, usually in combn w. *bhūta*. bhūta taccha tatha

  If it's usually "in combination" then perhaps it's not a separate meaning but some kind of compound meaning -- like "immensely huge" in English, two words that are similar, adjacent in meaning, and adjacent in the combined phrase
- *Bhūta* seems to mean -- natural, existing (in animate or inanimate nature)

The dictionary entry for *taccha* says that it's "derived from *tathā*+*ya*=*tath* -- *ya*" meaning "as it is," Sanskrit "tathya".

The "tathā" root is found elsewhere, for example:

- "tathata" (suchness) -- see [What is tathata?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12727/254)
- *tathagata* -- see [Why does the Buddha call himself the Tathāgata?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1629/254)

Used together I guess the two words might translate as, "something which is so, in nature/existence".

Answer (score 2):

The Pali in MN 58 is:

> In the same way, prince, the Realized One does not utter speech that
> he knows to be un**true**, **false** and pointless, and which is disliked by others. (Sujato translation)
>
> Evameva kho, rājakumāra, yaṁ tathāgato vācaṁ jānāti a**bhūta**ṁ **atacchaṁ**ṁ
> anatthasaṁhitaṁ sā ca paresaṁ appiyā amanāpā, na taṁ tathāgato vācaṁ
> bhāsati.

The word '[bhūta](https://suttacentral.net/define/bh%C5%ABta)' is used in many ways in the suttas, such as:

> Mendicants, do you see that this **has** **come to be**?”
>
> **Bhūta**midanti, bhikkhave, passathā”ti?
>
> [MN 38](https://suttacentral.net/mn38/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

Therefore, a better translation of "abhūtaṁ" in MN 58 would point to matters that "have not come to exist", "do not exist" or are "non-existent", in short, "unfactual/unevidenced/unsustantiated". Alternate translations are:

> Even so, Prince, whatever speech the Tathāgata knows to be **not fact**,
> not true, not connected with the goal, and that is not liked by
> others, disagreeable to them, that speech the Tathāgata does not utter (I.B. Horner)

> So too, Prince, such speech as a Tathāgata knows **does not represent what is [does not represent what has come to be]**, does not accord with reality, and is unconnected with good (Nyanamoli Thera)

> In the case of words that the Tathagata knows to be **unfactual**, untrue, unbeneficial (or: not connected with the goal), unendearing & disagreeable to others, he does not say them. (Thanissaro)

The other relevant Pali word in MN 58 is [taccha](https://suttacentral.net/define/taccha). I was going to suggest 'taccha' has a moral quality, such as meaning 'honest', because it is found in [Snp 2.9](https://suttacentral.net/snp2.9/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin), as follows:

> With what morality, what conduct, fostering what deeds, would a person
> lay the foundations right and reach the highest goal?
>
> Delighting in the teaching, enjoying the teaching, standing on the
> teaching, investigating the teaching, they’d never say anything that
> degraded the teaching, but would be guided by **genuine** words
> well-spoken (**tacchehi** nīyetha subhāsitehi).

However, the dictionary says [taccha](https://suttacentral.net/define/taccha) is derived from tathā + ya. The word 'tathā' appears to mean 'real', such as found in the following context:

> Mendicants, these four things are **real**, not unreal, not otherwise. Cattārimāni, bhikkhave, **tathā**ni avitathāni anaññathāni.
>
> What four? ‘This is suffering’ … ‘This is the origin of suffering’ … ‘This is the cessation of suffering’ … ‘This is the practice that leads to the cessation of suffering’ … These four things are real, not unreal, not otherwise.
>
> [SN 56.20](https://suttacentral.net/sn56.20/en/sujato?layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=asterisk&highlight=false&script=latin)

The above said, possibly taccha/tathā do have a moral quality, because what is described as 'tathā' in SN 56.20 are verbal statements by the Buddha rather than the mere natural lawful facts of suffering, origin, cessation & path.

In conclusion, without doing anymore research, I would speculate 'bhuta' means 'existent' and 'taccha' is a moral reflection upon what is 'existent' and thus means 'truthful/honest'.

> In the same way, prince, the Realized One does not utter speech that
> he knows to be unfactual/unevident, dishonest and unbeneficial, and which is disliked by others.
>
> (DD translation)